# ASP .NET Core how to Upload/Download large files that are ClientSide encrypted and store/read from EF DB

Tags: c#, reactjs, encryption, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a small React Application which should upload Files(large -> more than 5GB) to a ASP Dot Net Core API. The API will store the data in an Database with EF Core.
The problem is that I have to encrypt the Data on client side. The server will never touch unencrypted data.

How can I realize the clientside encryption and uploading? How does the download/decrypting work?

Comment: i thought there would be 101+ tools to do encryption.  you would have the private key in the React app so you can encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: but maybe i'm missing something? i'm not familiar with React per se

Comment: Maybe i dont have specified it correctly. My question is how to upload a large encrypted file to asp dot net core. 
Would it be an option to load the file in chunks, encrypt each chunk and upload the encrypted chunks to the server ?

Comment: How should the Action on Serverside look?